# Removing number of the end of the filename without the extension

Tags: bash

I have few files that I need to extract from the file extension and remove the number at the end of each file

```
test1.alarms
abcd1.alarms
test2.alarms
abcd2.alarms
```

Below is the code I used. The first part worked which removed the file extension and inserted back into the file, however, I was not able to remove the number of each file. After obtaining the result, I would then insert that back into the file.

```
for f in *.alarms; do
base=$(basename "$f" '.alarms')
sed --i "s/^/$base\:/" $f
db_name=`echo $base | grep -o [a-z]`
sed -ie "s/^/$db_name\:/" -i $f
done
```

result should be

```
test
abcd
test
abcd
```

Comment: `remove the number at the end of each file` - you want to `mv` the file? Right now your script tries manipulates the content of the file, not the filename, dunno, is this intentional?

Comment: How about `db_name=$(echo $f | sed 's/[0-9]\.alarms$//')`?

Comment: The dot has no special significance. If you want to remove `[0-9].alarm` then, well, do that. `basename` can't do it alone but the duplicate shows how to do various pattern substitutions (and then you don't need `basename` at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a single line solution:

```
printf '%s\n' *.alarms | sed 's/[[:digit:]]*\.alarms$//g'
```

When `printf` receives more arguments than values formats, it repeats the format string for each extra argument:

`printf '%s\n' *.alarms`: will expand all file names matching the globbing pattern `*.alarms` into an argument per file name.

The `%s\n` format string will cause each file name argument to be printed with a new-line character `\n`, effectively producing a newline delimited list of file-names, matching the `*.alarms` pattern.

This method is preferred to the unreliable parsing of an `ls`'s command output.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why you prefer `printf` over `ls`. Maybe see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 0):

I would use sed.

```
ls *.alarms | sed 's/[0-9][.]alarms//'
```

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is not an recommendable practice ^^

Comment: Yes, I see.  I've had scripts break because of parsing ls which is including ANSI markup for coloration.  Ugh, so annoying.  Because of this I'll generally use the --colors=never option.